# How do I get an RSS feed to work

Tags: rss, feed, theme-twenty-ten

Edited to clarify:

When I changed my WordPress theme to TwentyTen, my RSS feed stopped working. I had it set up to feed new blog posts (my WP site) to my primary website.

I tried doing a number of things, but I can't remember what I did. However, at one point, the feed started working (but that may have been with another theme).

My WP site is at http://blog.jeffbloom.net. The site I want to feed to (near the bottom of the homepage) is http://jeffbloom.wikidot.com.

At this point, I'm not even sure if TwentyTen supports RSS feeds. Does anyone know? Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this issue? Although at this point I'd rather not change themes yet again, is there a (free) theme that will handle feeds without much hassle?

Thanks!

Comment: Both feed url works fine http://blog.jeffbloom.net/feed/ , http://blog.jeffbloom.net/feed/ .You can use many feed plugins out there.

Comment: Ronald - Thanks for responding. But, I still can't seem to get it to work. I have a lot of feeds coming into my main site on Wikidot, but I still can't get my blog feed to work. But, did you get the feed from my blog to work? Also, I have tried a number of Feed Subscription plugins, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an invalid feed. 
There's a `<center></center>` tag at the beginning opening the file instead of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. You need to fix that.

I don't know where that comes from, probably from some post being not well formatted, or from some plugin or your theme.

Try disabling all your plugins and then reactivating them one by one to see which one might cause the problem. If not, try to change theme and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. What file has the <center></center> tag?

Comment: Is that the file that is generated by the RSS Subscribe button? If so, how do I edit that? (My knowledge of this is just enough to make me dangerous... :) I just fumble my way through and learn as I go...